# to meet or meeting: when talking about an activity

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> I enjoy to meet my friends and grab lunch together.

I know that the phrase above is incorrect, that it should be:

> I enjoy meeting my friends and grab lunch together.

But I don't understand why we use gerund form of a verb when we're talking about and activity that will continue to go on.

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: It's just the rules of English grammar. Do you mean what's the historical reason for the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Enjoy” and “like” have similar meaning here.

However, unlike the word “like” the word “enjoy” cannot be used with “to” followed by an infinitive.

> I like to meet my friends and grab lunch together

This is a valid use of like +to.

When you aren’t using “to” then the thing you like is a direct object which means it is a noun or pronoun. That is why the gerund is used.

> I like meeting my friends and grabbing lunch together.

Since “enjoy” cannot be used with “to” we use a gerund to describe the activity as an object.

> I enjoy meeting my friends and grabbing lunch together.